# merging two data.frames by different row.names in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have two data.frames and I want to join them together by row.names. But the row.names are not equal, I tried this but it does not work

```
df1 <- data.frame(row.names = c('S.5.0U0','S.6.0U1','S.7.0U2','S.8.0U3'),vara=c(-1.2,15,8.5,0),varb=c(-29,29,2.6,5))
df2 <- data.frame(row.names = c('5U','6U','7U'),var1=c(-0.5,1.5,58),var2=c(-2.09,-12,2.6))

df1
      vara  varb
S.5.0U0 -1.2 -29.0
S.6.0U1 15.0  29.0
S.7.0U2  8.5   2.6
S.8.0U3  0     5

df2
   var1   var2
5.U0 -0.5  -2.09
6.U1  1.5 -12.00
7.U2 58.0   2.60

merge <- df1 %>% mutate(name = case_when(
         name == 'S.5.U' ~ '5U',
         name == 'S.6.U' ~ '6U',
         name == 'S.7.U' ~ '7U',
T ~ name)) %>% 
  left_join(., df2, by = 'name')

Error:Problem with `mutate()` input `name`. x Objekt 'name' not found i Input `name` is `case_when(...)`.
```

Why is this not working? Why can it not find `name` although I specyfied it?

EDIT:
The output should look like this

```
merge
          vara  varb var1  var2
S.5.0U0 5U  -1.2   -29 -0.5   -2.09
S.6.0U1 6U   15     29  1.5   -12
S.7.0U2 7U   8.5   2.6  58    2.6
```

I edited my example data, because I realised it does not fit the real data properly.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this line `T ~ name`?  There is no `name` value to assign. Can you show your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`name` column is not present in your data, you have them as rownames. Make rownames as column, remove unwanted characters from it using `gsub` and then join the data.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

df1 %>%
  rownames_to_column('name') %>%
  mutate(name1 = gsub('[S.0]|\\d$', '', name)) %>%
  inner_join(df2 %>%
  rownames_to_column('name'), by = c('name1' = 'name')) %>%
  column_to_rownames('name')

#        vara  varb name1 var1   var2
#S.5.0U0 -1.2 -29.0    5U -0.5  -2.09
#S.6.0U1 15.0  29.0    6U  1.5 -12.00
#S.7.0U2  8.5   2.6    7U 58.0   2.60
```

---

If the data is not the same as the post and there is no pattern which we can use to match `name` values we can also use `case_when` to match values individually.

```
df1 %>%
  rownames_to_column('name') %>%
  mutate(name1 = case_when(name == 'S.5.U' ~ '5U',
    name == 'S.6.U' ~ '6U',
    name == 'S.7.U' ~ '7U',
    name == 'S.8.U' ~ '8U',
    TRUE ~ name)) %>%  
  inner_join(df2 %>% rownames_to_column('name'), by = c('name1' = 'name')) %>%
  column_to_rownames('name')
```

Comment: Thank you @Ronak With your solution,the colnames are right, but unfortunately 'No data available'.

Comment: Did you assign the data back? `df <- df1 %>% rownames_to_column....rest of the code`

Comment: Yes, I did... I think it has something to do with my ```gsub```

Comment: Are you using the same data as shown in your post? It works for me without any error on that data. If your real data is not same as in your post you can also use `case_when` to replace values individually. Check updated answer.

Comment: No, that was a reprex. ```...mutate(name1 = gsub('^ST|\\.','', name)) %>%
  mutate(name1 = gsub('.0U', '.U', name)) %>%...``` I suspect this is not correct when I want to replace more than one thing...

Comment: If the solution with `case_when` doesn't work as well you can update your post with subset of your real data maybe regex needs minor adjusting to match your real data.

Comment: @takeITeasy My updated answer works for the new data shared. Can you check that?